# Как узнать громкость музыки в pyglet(или как то по другому)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как узнать громкость музыки в pyglet(или как то по другому)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так – `player.volume`. [Документация](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/programming_guide/media.html#controlling-playback)